# Copying neo4j graph from local machine to VM

Tags: neo4j

I want to copy my entire neo4j graph(all nodes and relationships) created so far from my local machine(windows) to VM(windows). Is there any way I can achieve the same. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dump of the database and restore the database dump in the VM. Other than that, you can use APOC to export the node and relationship information and import it in your VM. For more information about the APOC procedures to export and import data you can take a look at the documentation: https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/export/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way:

1. Stop the neo4j service on both local machine and VM.
2. copy the /data/ folder with all its content to the new location.
3. Start the neo4j service in the new location.

Comment: data folder is having two folders inside it: databases and transactions and both these folders are empty, may be I am looking at some other data folder. 
It would be of great help if you please elaborate location of this data folder and where do I need to copy this. Thanks

Comment: you need to check in your neo4j.conf file the parameter dbms.directories.data , check here: https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/how-do-i-define-my-graphdb-at-a-path-other-than-under-neo4j-home-for-windows/

Comment: dbms.directories.data =data only in neo4j.conf file. Earlier it was commented, now I have uncommented it. What next do I need to do? please guide